# Filter by category react, fetching information from 3 different api's and displaying them in a card format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

hopefully you are having a great day!
I am making a website for uni group project,
Logic: I'll post data from database to localhost:3001, this is backend made using node.
Then I'll collect that information into 3 const (foodList, clothesList, techList) and then add value of these const into a variable called 'data'
data will be used to render cards to display on website.

Now the problem I am having is, in Logic.js, that when I made filter for categories, it is partially working, but new data is not rendered and displayed on website

Categories.js:

```js
const catgs = [
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "category": "Food"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "category": "Clothes"
    },
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "category": "Tech"
    }
]

export {catgs};
```

CheckBox.js:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Checkbox, Collapse } from 'antd'
import { useState } from 'react'

function CheckBox(props) {
    const { Panel } = Collapse;
    const [Checked, setChecked] = useState([])

    const catgs = [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "category": "Food"
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "category": "Clothes"
        },
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "category": "Tech"
        }
    ];

    const handleToggle = (value) => {
        const currentIndex = Checked.indexOf(value)
        const newChecked = [...Checked]

        if(currentIndex === -1){
            newChecked.push(value)
        }else{
            newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1)
        }

        setChecked(newChecked)

        props.handleFilters(newChecked)
    }

    const renderCheckboxLists = () => catgs.map((value, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <Checkbox
                onChange = {() => handleToggle(value._id)}
                type="checkbox"
                checked= {Checked.indexOf(value._id) === -1 ? false : true }
            />
            <span>{value.category}</span>
        </React.Fragment>
    ))

    return (
        <div>
            
            <Collapse defaultActiveKey={['0']} >
                <Panel header="Categories" key="1">
                    {renderCheckboxLists()}
                </Panel>
            </Collapse>

        </div>
    )
}

export default CheckBox
```

Logic.js:

```js
import React from 'react'
import  {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import Axios from 'axios';
import { Col, Card, Row } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import CheckBox from './CheckBox';

const Logic = () => {

  const { Meta } = Card;

    const [foodList, setfoodList] = useState([]);
    const [clothesList, setclothesList] = useState([]);
    const [techList, settechList] = useState([]);
    let  [data, setdata] = useState([])
    const [Limit, setLimit] = useState(8);
    const [Filters, setFilters] = useState({
      category: []
    })
     
    useEffect(() => {
      Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get/food').then((response) => {
       setfoodList(response.data);
      });
    }, []);
    
     useEffect(() => {
       Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get/clothes').then((response) => {
        setclothesList(response.data);
       });
     }, []);
     
    useEffect(() => {
      Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get/tech').then((response) => {
       settechList(response.data);
      });
    }, []);


    data = [...foodList, ...clothesList, ...techList];
   
    const onLoadMore = () => {
      
      setLimit(Limit + 8);
    
    }

    

    const renderCards = data.slice(0, Limit).map((val, index) => {
      return <Col key={index} lg={6} md={8} xs={24}>
          <Card 
             
              hoverable={true}
              cover = {<a href = {val.Link}>{val.Image}</a>}
          >
              <Meta
                  title={val.Company}
                  description={val.Description}
              />
          </Card>
      </Col>
  })


  const showFilteredResults = (filters) => {
    
  }
  
  const handleFilters = (filters, category) => {
    const newFilters = { ...Filters }
    newFilters[category] = filters
    showFilteredResults(newFilters)
    setFilters(newFilters)
}
      
    return (
        <div style = {{ width : '75%', margin: '3rem auto' }}>
            <div style = {{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <h2>Eco Friendly Companies </h2>
            </div>
            
            <CheckBox
                handleFilters = {filters => handleFilters(filters, "category")}
            />  

            {data.length === 0 ?
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '300px', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <h2>No post yet...</h2>
                </div> :
                <div>
                    <Row gutter={[16, 16]}>

                        {renderCards}

                    </Row>


                </div>
            }
           
      <br></br>
        <div style = {{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <button onClick={onLoadMore}>Load More</button>
        </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Logic
```